# My selenium script is scraping the variables in the first link of google maps correctly , but when it loads the second link it shows some error

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium4

The goal of this script is to access business names from an Excel file and then search it on google maps and scrape the required data. The issue is that the script is running correctly and scraping the data of the first business name on google maps. But when the second link loads and the data table occurs it throws some error.

How can I sort it out?

Feel free to run this script on your compiler. You can create an Excel file and write any two names in the a column of Excel file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
import time

import pandas as pd 
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
geckodriver_path = Service(r'E:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=geckodriver_path, options=Options)

import pandas as pd

# Load the Excel workbook and select the sheet
workbook = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\muneeb\Desktop\Business name.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active

# Create a list of business names from the first column of the sheet
business_names = [cell.value for cell in sheet['A']] 
for business_name in business_names:
    # Go to Google Maps
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/@24.9349012,67.2006144,15z')
    
    # Find the search box and enter the business name
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchboxinput")
    search_box.send_keys(business_name)
    # Find the first result and click on it
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mL3xi")
    element.click()
    
    # Wait for the business details to load
    time.sleep(20)`
    # Scrape the business details
    name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span[1]").text
    phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[5]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
    website = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[4]/a/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
    reviews = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]/span').text
    address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text

print(len(phone),len(name),len(website),len(reviews),len(address))
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Muneeb data\Webscraping\googlemaps_scraping.py", line 58, in <module>
    phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[5]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\muneeb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 830, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\muneeb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\muneeb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[5]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]"}
```

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: Did you verify that the phone was available for the business_name raising the error? Sometimes there is no phone [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wGpI.png) for example

Comment: Yes, my script is working fine now and scraping the data accurately, but I'm still facing one issue 
It scraps all the data of all links but in excel file it shows data of one site only

Can you help me in this situation?

Comment: Instead of adding an answer with new code, edit your original question, if you don't know how [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUGgc.png)

Comment: Do you want one excel file with data of all sites, or you want a separate excel file for each site?